What is this mark under my cat's eye?
My wife and I adopted an adult cat from a shelter a few months ago. She seems generally in good health, but there's a small mark under her left eye, that looks like a small scrape or something, with no fur.  It's been there since we got it, and whatever happened to the fur, it's not growing back.  I can't help but wonder, where does a mark like this come from, and is it any sort of cause for concern?


Ask your vet, who can examine it directly. I would guess a scar, but that says nothing about  when or how acquired. Doesn't look like anything I'd worry about unless it is oozing it changing

this might be a old tiny scar that is fully healed,it is very unlikely to cause any problems in the future.i can see 3 tiny marks on yor cat`s nose that might be the same age as the one below the eye.
